# Difficulty implementing BFS for traversal of graph

Tags: java, algorithm, search, graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

I have an adjacency matrix adj which is defined below:

```
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
```

I'm wracking my head around designing a BFS algorithm to traverse the graph given a starting position and an ending position.

My best attempt does yield a series of moves, but not the shortest.

```
boolean[] pass = new boolean[9]; //if a move has been done, don't redo it
int s = 0; //starting position
int e = 2; //ending position
int[][] matrix; //the adjacency matrix previous defined

public List<Integer> BFS(int[][] matrix, int s) {
    List<Integer> paths = new LinkedList();
    List<Integer> shortest = new LinkedList();
    pass[s] = true; //starting position has been indexed
    paths.add(0,s); //insert part of path to front of list
    while (paths.isEmpty() == false) {
        int element = paths.get(0); //peek at first element
        shortest.add(element); //add it to shortest path
        int node = paths.remove(0); //remove from path
        if (element == e) { //if we've reached the end
            return shortest; //hopefully found shortest path
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                //if adjacent element hasn't been indexed
                if (pass[i] == false && matrix[node][i] == 1) {
                    pass[i] = true;
                    paths.add(0,i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Printing the returned List yields:

```
[0, 3, 6, 4, 5, 8, 2]
```

When the actual result should be:

```
[0, 3, 4, 5, 2]
```

It seems to me the path it's taking is something like:

```
[0, 3, 6, backtrack to 3, 4, 5, 8, backtrack to 5, 2]
```

What is wrong with my algorithm? How do I find the shortest path given a start and end point?

[Here](http://ideone.com/fork/2EfMvp)'s an IDEone to illustrate.

Comment: Your BFS traversal is OK, but you don't extract the shortest path correctly. You are adding *every* node you process to the shortest path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't extract the shortest path correctly. You are adding *every* node you process to the shortest path.

If you want to use BFS to find the shortest path, you have to keep track of the shortest path to every intermediate node by storing "back edges" and only in the end you can put them together to find the shortest path.

For every node that you add to the queue, store the node that made you arrive at this node as "back edge":

```
if (pass[i] == false && matrix[node][i] == 1) {
    pass[i] = true;
    paths.add(0,i);

    // Add this:
    back[i] = node;
}
```

Then once your traversal is finished, you can use those references to find the full path by going those "back edges" backwards from the end node. It will lead you (backwards) to the start node on the shortest path:

```
int node = e;
while (node != s) {
    shortest.add(0, node);
    node = back[node];
}
shortest.add(0, s);
```

**Update**:

Thanks to your comment I just realized that there is an additional problem with your code. You are adding new nodes to the front of the list and process them from the front, too. So you have effectively a stack, not a queue. That makes your algorithm effectively a Depth-first search (DFS) instead of a Breadth-first search (BFS). The DFS will give you a correct path from `s` to `e`, but not necessarily the shortest one.

In order to treat your list `paths` (which should better be named `queue`, btw.) as queue instead of stack, you have to read and write from opposite ends, e.g. to add to the back (instead of the front) change your list adding line

```
paths.add(0, i);
```

to

```
paths.add(i);
```

Comment: I follow, but taking this method provides the output `[3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`.

Comment: @gator: I guess you mixed the "old" `shortest` list with the new one.

Comment: @gator: See http://goo.gl/IydTAe You can execute it online and check that it returns the correct result `[0, 3, 4, 5, 2]`.

Comment: this works for the given adjacency matrix, but it doesn't work for all adjacency matrices. See http://ideone.com/fork/PTVtNj the printed list is `[0, 6, 7, 13, 19, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 23, 17, 11, 5]` (14 elements) when the shortest path is `[0, 6, 7, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 11, 5]` (11 elements).

Comment: @gator: I see. Just found the other problem with your code and updated the answer.

Comment: Cheers, you've been a great help! Every resource I've been following has used distance calculations or colors or what-have-you to determine the most shallow path to take, it's difficult to transcribe for my purposes, but you've steered me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

The `shortest` array in your implementation is not what you think it is. It is just the list of all vertices found, not the shortest path, as (as you have notices) BFS sometimes has to follow paths that do not lead toward the target vertex.

What you need to do is for each vertex `v` store its "parent" — the vertex where you got from to `v`:

```
       if (pass[i] == false && matrix[node][i] == 1) {
            pass[i] = true;
            parent[i] = node;
            paths.add(0,i);
       }
```

Then after the main BFS loop you go from the target vertex back to source using links stored in `parent`:

```
// pseudocode
cur = e;
while cur != s
    answer.add_at_end(cur)
    cur = parent[cur];
```